# Texture paint not staying in object mode

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting, object-mode

On blender 2.7, I created a model and i was texture painting using an image (that i previously used made using UV mapping). I've done this before and it worked but this time the texture I want is only visible on the texture paint mode - not on object mode. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I've added some pictures below showing what's happening. It's my first time animating and i could really use the help thanks.
[image]

[image]

Here is a screen shot of my nodes for reference! (sorry, bit of a newbie here, hope these are right)[image]

Comment: The material shows you are using nodes, but the texture is not present there, you’ll need to add a texture node and reference it. You are using 2.7 and Blender material, not cycles, so I’m not sure how you intend to proceed.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, do you know how i could add and reference a texture node? I've changed to cycles but im still struggling a bit. Thanks, my mark for this project goes towards my high school certificate and so im kind of stressed and confused!

Comment: Shift-A add menu will give you a list of types, add an image texture node and reference your painted texture. Add a texture coordinate node for us input or an up map node and reference the specific up layer name. The texture node should plug into your shader node color input.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is pink, it means that blender cant find your textures. It's probably an issue with your shading. Would you mind showing your nodes?

Comment: Hey, I added a screenshot to the post, i have altered them at all. Hope that it was right!